# Is it possible to add worker nodes with different architectures to kubespray cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to add worker nodes with different architectures to kubespray cluster?

Suppose I want to have master & worker node on Intel x64 running Flatcar. Would it be possible to add other arm (Rasbperry PI 3B) worker nodes, preferably running Raspberry PI Server OS?

Comment: What have you tried and what outcome is it producing for you?

Comment: @mdaniel I haven't tried yet, wanted to ask first, because I haven't found any mention on multi-arch clusters in kubespray docs. Hence I wanted to know if there are any known limitations/quirks, such as "don't use CNI X because they don't have multi-arch builds", or "use exactly the same OS distributions because file system layout must be the same", or simply "it is not possible at all because of X and Y"